# How do I use GoRouter with urls that need to access async functions?

Tags: firebase-authentication, flutter-go-router

I have a Flutter app which uses Firebase.  I started using Go Router recently.

One of the requirements that I have is to verify email.  This will send an email to the user with a link inside it.

When the link is clicked by the user, The redirect function in GoRouter is called with a CODE in the url to check if the email is valid. This check requires making async call to the server.  The redirect function in GoRouter does not handle async function calls.

I checked Go Router docs but did not find any info on how to handle this case.  Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks